# pyspark with HCatalog table in Zeppelin

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have created a table `HCatalog` table with partitions mapping to some zip files in S3.

In Zeppelin, I created a paragraph using the `%pyspark` module with the following codes:

**Paragraph 1:**

```py
%pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

hc = HiveContext( sc )
f_req_2h = hc.table( "default.f_req_2h" )  # a HCatalog table in the default schema"
print f_req_sh.count()
f_req_2h.registerTempTable("f_req_2h")
```

When I ran it, so far so good. Then I created a second paragraph to query the f_req_2h table, which was registered in paragraph 1, as follows:

**Paragraph 2:**

```sql
%sql
select * from f_req_2h limit 1;
```

I got an `"table not found"` error. Any help or pointer is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an expected behavior. Each table or `DataFrame` in Spark is bound to a specific `SQLContext` which has been used to create it and cannot be accessed outside it.

Apache Zeppelin initializes both `SparkContext` and `SQLContext` which are shared between interpreters and can be accessed as `sc` and `sqlContext` respectively. You should these instances, not create another one, if you want to benefit from interpreter interoperability. In other words don't create custom context by use default one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks zero323 for your pointer. I removed the HiveContext and revised the code as follows and it works:

```
%pyspark

f_req_2h = sqlContext.table( "default.f_req_2h" ) 
# a HCatalog table in the default schema"  
print f_req_sh.count()  
f_req_2h.registerTempTable("f_req_2h")
```